# How can I extract certain information from a string in python?

Tags: python, html, string

I am trying to use python to extract certain information from html code.
for example:

```
<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a> 
and I would like to get result : Visit the Useful Tips Section

<div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">
<b>Menu</b><br />
HTML<br />
CSS<br />
and I would like to get Menu HTML CSS
```

In other word, I wish to get everything between <>and<>
I am trying to write a python function that takes the html code as a string, and then extract information from there. I am stuck at string.split('<').

Comment: Have you tried using any HTML parsing library? Or you can actually process the file by removing all the tags (a bit tricky to do with `<script>` tag, though).

Answer (score 3):

You should use a proper HTML parsing library, such as the [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

```
string = '<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>'
re.findall('<[^>]*>(.*)<[^>]*>', string) //return 'Visit the Useful Tips Section'
```

Comment: [I wouldn't recommend a regexp-based solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/566644)

Comment: @lazyr: depends on the context... If you know enough about the markup structure and there's no ambiguity, a mere regexp can JustWork with way less overhead than a full blown HTML parser. But you indeed have to know when the regexp is ok and when it's time to go for your HTML parser...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) html parser.

```
>>> import lxml.html as lh
>>> st = ''' load your above html content into a string '''
>>> d = lh.fromstring(st)
>>> d.text_content()

'Visit the Useful Tips Section \nand I would like to get result : Visit the Useful Tips Section\n\n\nMenu\nHTML\nCSS\nand I would
like to get Menu HTML CSS\n'
```

or you can do

```
>>> for content in d.text_content().split("\n"):
...     if content:
...             print content
...
Visit the Useful Tips Section
and I would like to get result : Visit the Useful Tips Section
Menu
HTML
CSS
and I would like to get Menu HTML CSS
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are trying to strip out the HTML tags and keep only the text.

You can define a regular expression that represents the tags.
Then substitute all matches with the empty string.

Example:

```
def remove_html_tags(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return p.sub('', data)
```

References:

[Example](http://love-python.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/strip-html-tags-using-python.html)

[Docs about python regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) - it gets much less cranky with mal-formed html.